# jQuery - How to check which element is being hovered over (but NOT any specific element!)

Tags: jquery, hover, mousemove, mouseout, mouseleave

I would like to use jQuery to determine which element is currently being hovered over. It could be any element on the page, meaning that `mouseover`, `mouseout`, `mouseenter`, and `mouseleave` do not apply here, as they would relate to a specific element.

Here's a quick sample:

```
$(window).bind('mousemove', function() {
    if (elementBeingHoveredOver.attr('id') != 'foo') {
        // ... (Do some cool stuff here) ...
        $(window).unbind('mousemove');
    }
});
```

I know, I know, it looks like it would be better to bind a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event handler to the `#foo` element and just do it that way, but the mouse often moves too quickly to register a `mouseleave` event, so I want to try it this way.

Any ideas on how to determine `elementBeingHoveredOver`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(window).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr('id') != 'foo') {
        // ... (Do some cool stuff here) ...
        $(window).unbind('mousemove');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

While I still suggest you to bind to mouse move event of every element on page, here is a way to find elements by mouse position:

when you bind to mouse move event of the document you can get the cursor position using `pageX` and `pageY`:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    alert(e.pageX);
    alert(e.pageY);
});
```

then by using `.offset()` you can get elements position on page:

```
function elementBeingHoveredOver(mouseX, mouseY) {

    $('*').each(function() {
        var x = $(this).offset().left;
        var y = $(this).offset().top;
        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();

        if (x <= mouseX && y <= mouseY && (x + width) >= mouseX && (y + height) >= mouseY) {
            return $(this);
        }
    });

    return null;    
}
```